# Python disabled logging slowing script

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, logging, optimization

I am using the built in Python "logging" module for my script. When I turn verbosity to "info" it seems like my "debug" messages are significantly slowing down my script.

Some of my "debug" messages print large dictionaries and I'm guessing Python is expanding the text before realizing "debug" messages are disabled. Example:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
logger.debug(f"Large Dict Object: {pp.pformat(obj)}")
```

How can I improve my performance? I'd prefer to still use Python's built in logging module. But need to figure out a "clean" way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already [a feature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor) of logging for the feature mentioned by `dankal444`, which is slightly neater:

```
if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    logger.debug(f"Large Dict Object: {pp.pformat(obj)}")
```

Another possible approach is to use %-formatting, which only does the formatting when actually needed (the logging event has to be processed by a handler as well as a logger to get to that point). I know f-strings are the new(ish) hotness and are performant, but it all depends on the exact circumstances as to which will offer the best result.

An example of taking advantage of lazy %-formatting:

```
class DeferredFormatHelper:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, *kwargs):
        self.func = func  # assumed to return a string
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        # This is called because the format string contains
        # a %s for this logging argument, lazily if and when
        # the formatting needs to happen
        return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

if logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    arg = DeferredFormatHelper(pp.pformat, obj)
    logger.debug('Large Dict Object: %s', arg)
```

Comment: It *is* lazier, because the %-formatting gets applied some time after the logging call, if it's needed. The f-string formatting happens before the logging call, even if the message never makes it out because of logger or handler levels or a filter blocking it.

Comment: I'm talking about e.g. `logger.debug('foo %i', n)` - notice the subtle difference.

Comment: Does that Deferred stuff make sense, guarded by that `if`? Seems if you get there, you *will* log it.

Comment: It does make sense. You will make the logging call, but that doesn't necessarily mean it will get output. Have you looked at all the documentation?

Comment: So it's possible that `logger.debug` doesn't log even though `logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` is true? The documentation makes it sound like the latter precisely means that `logger.debug` does log (although no, sorry, the page is long and I didn't read it all).

Comment: Can someone please provide official reference which states that %-formatting gets applied after the logging call and f-string formatting gets applied before the logging call?

Comment: @JoyChopra There's no "official reference" - it can be inferred from how f-strings work.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the current level is good enough:

```
if logger.getEffectiveLevel() <= logging.DEBUG:
    logger.debug(f"Large Dict Object: {pp.pformact(obj)}")
```

This is not super clean but best that I can think of. You just need to encompass with this if performance bottlenecks

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify where your bottleneck is, but if it's because of the pprint library, your logger will never have a chance to do anything about it. Rewriting to clarify.

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

large_object = {"very": "large container"}
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

# This is done first.
formatted_msg = pp.pformat(large_object)
# It's already formatted when it's sent to your logger.
logger.debug(f"Large dict object: {formatted_msg}")
```